# Dynamic Gallery is not working online but working on localhost

Tags: asp.net

i have dynamic web Gallery in light box which is working fine in localhost but when i publish a site and then upload on server, gallery is not showing the images online...

i had to take the page property "AutoEventwireup=true" because i need to call page events automatically... and i think it`s creating problem online but working fine in localhost..

is my assumption correct about AutoEventWireup="true"???

**Note:** i have  already granted a permission to image folder in server so it`s not a cause of configuring the IIS...

Any Help or suggestion plz?

**Updated:**
Download the Demo of photo Gallery (no database required it will be handled by xml data)
You can upload from admin and display to client, there are two pages first is imageupload.aspx in Admin folder which will be uploaded and second is photogallery.aspx where images will be displayed and the third one which i have to mention is xml file in which xml nodes are created, xml file is inside a data folder

**Download Link**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_f0_xt7mMiwTXc2T0dFS0MzWE0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

No your assumption is not correct. AutoEventWireup="true" allows you to handle standard page events using their default names, for example: -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

If you set AutoEventWireup to false, you must explicitly override the named function: -

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Can you post your code please - the page, and the image gallery ?

Comment: Thankx @sh1rts for your reply i have updated my question and uploaded the photo gallery file that you can download.. can you help me why this is not showing the images online?? although i have granted the permission to only data folder.. because data folder contain the all the images for photo gallery

Comment: Well.. I got your sample working on my machine and then published it to one of our UAT servers; it worked just fine ?

Comment: Can I email your zealousDevelopers address and give you the URL I've published to ? You can see it working .. it must be a permissions issue mate, or possibly the XML file is marked as read-only ?

Comment: Yup plz email me the address

Comment: OK done. Can you let me know when you're done with it, so I can take it offline.

Comment: I've taken the site offline; let me know if you need it back. Suffice to say, it's not a problem with your code - which works just fine.

Comment: mate i did`nt receive your email in my address "shahbazbaig01@gmail.com

Comment: ahh - I sent it to the contact email address for your company. I'm at home now (I'm in Sydney so I think we're 6 hours ahead of you), I'm happy to put the test site back up for you tomorrow if you need it ?